# Disabling a cboxTitle Element in jQuery Colobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colorbox

I have an icon on my webpage with the following attributes:

```
<a class="iframe cboxElement" href="contact.html" title= "Contact Performance Analytics">
<i class="fa fa-phone-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

The reason for the title is to display on mouse over but when I open the colorbox it shows as it's title. How could I hide or disable it?

I adjusted my script tag as below but I must be doing something wrong:

```
<script> 

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width: "700px", height:"300px"});
                $('.iframe cboxElement').colorbox({title: '' });
            });



        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `null` value while initializing the colorbox plugin, like:

```
$('.selector').colorbox({
  title: '' // Setting Title to null
});
```

Have a look at the demo snippet below:

```js
$('.link').colorbox({
  title: ''
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="link" title="This is a link">Link</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

## Update:

You are using wrong syntax for select the element

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.iframe.cboxElement').colorbox({
    title: '',
    iframe: true,
    width: "700px",
    height:"300px"
  });
});
```

Instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width: "700px", height:"300px"});
  $('.iframe cboxElement').colorbox({title: '' });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @NanaThompson You are using wrong CSS selector. You are missing a '.' between `iframe` & `cboxElement` Do it like this - `$('.iframe.cboxElement').colorbox({title: '' });`. Hope you understand. I've updated my answer as well. Keep in mind you are initializing the same element again using it.